# How can we drop a column and add a column with same name in a same table in a single NHibernate transaction?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

Environment: C#, NHibernate, SQL server.

The scenario:

I have to modify a column in a table and at the run time only we come to know how we need to modify. So, instead of modifying the column, we just drop the existing column and add a new column with same name. We don't intend to keep the data of that column also. Therefore, add/delete method should work fine. One constraint is, both delete and add should happen in a single transaction.

The problem:

If the column which I have to delete and re-add has some data, it doesn't work. It gives me this error:

`ALTER TABLE only allows columns to be added that can contain nulls, or have a DEFAULT definition specified, or the column being added is an identity or timestamp column, or alternatively if none of the previous conditions are satisfied the table must be empty to allow addition of this column.`

I was assuming that as I am deleting the column first, re-adding shouldn't be a problem but it's not doing that.

The simplified code:

```
var dropColumn = string.Format("alter table {0} drop column {1} ",tableName, fieldName);
Session.CreateSQLQuery(dropColumn).ExecuteUpdate();

var addColumn = string.Format("alter table {0} add {1} nvarchar(255) not null",tableName,fieldName);
Session.CreateSQLQuery(addColumn).ExecuteUpdate();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error says: "that can contain nulls, or have a DEFAULT" and in your second query you have "not null". So what value ( if not null ) do you want be in that column after column addition? If you have answer for that use default value constraint.